# 8086 program to find sum of Even numbers in a given series

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I am trying to find sum of 5 EVEN nos stored in memory from 500 to 504. I cannot get the required result. Can you please me find my logic mistake?

I AM TRYING TO DO IT USING 8086 ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE

```
mov [500],4
mov [501],30
mov [502],15
mov [503],7
mov [504],98 
mov bl,00
mov si,500
mov cx,5

l1:
  mov dl,[si]
  test dl,01
  jnz next

; if even
  add dl,bl
  inc si
  loop l1
  jmp exit
; if odd
next: 
  inc si
  jmp l1
exit:
  mov ah,4ch
  int 21h 
  ret
```

Comment: `add dl,bl` is reversed. Should be `add bl, dl` if you want to accumulate the sum in `bl`. Also the `next` part does not decrement `cx`. You want a `loop` there too. You could also share that code. PS: learn to use your simulator to single step the code.

Comment: @Jester I cannot control the value of counter for both the labels. Help me with that please :(

Answer (score 0):

S
DF

```
mov [501],30
mov [502],15
mov [503],7
mov [504],98 
mov bl,00
mov si,500
mov cx,5       
  l1:
  mov dl,[si]
  test dl,01
  jnz next  
; if even
  add bl,dl
  inc si
  jmp l2
; if odd 
next: 
  inc si
  jmp l2
  l2:
  dec cx;
  cmp cx,00
  jnz l1
  jmp exit
exit:
  mov ah,4ch
  int 21h
ret
```

FINALLY DID IT